# Not answered Passing full DTO object to delete method

Tags: asp.net-mvc, telerik-mvc

How to pass full dto object to delete action method.

The use case is for concurrency checking, I want to pass "version" field and "id" of the row to delete method.

How to implement that ?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot pass a complex object to the Delete action method. What you can do is add more than one data key. The grid will pass all data keys to your delete action method:

```
<%= Html.Telerik().Grid()
        .DataKeys(keys =>
        {
           keys.Add(c => c.id);
           keys.Add(c => c.version).RouteKey("version");
        }
%>

public ActionResult Delete(int id, string version)
{
}
```